# Dimension of Lie subgroup and zero of induced vector field

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

I am trying to find all connected subgroups of $SO(3)$ and, while solving, came up with a following question.

Let some one-dimensional subgroup $G$ of $SO(3)$ act on $S^2$ and induce a vector field by taking a derivative at $e$. By definition this vector field is smooth, so, by hairy ball theorem, there is point $p$ such that vector field at this point is zero.

Is it true that stabilizer of $p$ is one-dimensional Lie subgroup of $G$? If yes, how can one demonstrate it.

Thanks!

Comment: @JasonDeVito we assign to a point $p$ an image of $1$ under differential at this point.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I added condition on $G$ to be one-dimensianal, if you meant it.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but yes, it is true.  Restrict your action to $G$, then use Lemma 3.1.4 here https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math661/LectureNotesLee.pdf (whose proof is left as an excercise!)